# Access Firebase Cloud Storage file from Flutter Web through redirect

Tags: firebase, http, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

My following setup

- A Flutter web app (`web.my-example.com`) loads a file through my custom API (`www.my-example.com/api/file`).
- My Cloud function API (`www.my-example.com/api/file`) redirects the call to a signed firebase cloud storage URL (`https://storage.googleapis.com/my-example.appspot.com/files/D39757EF-A1E6-427B-B157-FCFB154D19B4/file.jpg?GoogleAccessId=<project-id>v%40appspot.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1695902142&Signature=<signature>`)

This does not work because uf cors issues. I have an allow all (`"*"`) both on my API as well as on firebase storage.

Is there a way to make this work or can I not use redirects within browsers for files at all?